# Control IOException en lectura archivos binarios

Tags: java

La cuestión es que haciendo pruebas cree un método para leer un archivo binario, pongo el código y pregunto:

```
    public void lecturaDatos(){
  File f = new File("archivomodelos.mod");

  try{ 
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
       DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis); 
          modeloAto = dis.readUTF();
          while(modeloAto != null){
              modeloMod = dis.readUTF();
              cuantasPilas = dis.readInt();
              System.out.println("\nModelo Ato: "+modeloAto+"\tModelo Mod: "+modeloMod+"\tCuantas Pilas lleva: "+cuantasPilas);

              modeloAto = dis.readUTF();
          }
          dis.close();


  } catch(IOException ex){         
      ex.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Ocurrió un error al leer");
  }
```

Por los errores que me sale tengo "casi" claro que el problema está al intentar seguir leyendo archivos cuando no existen más filas. Siempre me salta el error, pero no se si hay algún método que me me diga si hay algo más que leer y en su defecto seguir con la letura o pararla. He mirado en (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html) y no veo que DataInputStream tenga algún método para ello, pero estoy seguro que tiene que haber algo para evitar que salte el catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `available` disponible en `DataInputStream`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#available

```
try {
    // código anterior
    while(dis.available()>0) {
        // lee caracteres UTF-8
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (dis!=null)
        dis.close();
}
```

Comment: Gracias! No se me ocurrió usar ese método, sinceramente pensaba que era solo para FileInputStream. Aún me queda mucho por aprender :D. Por lo que veo también cometí el error de no leer bien la documentación y quedarme en un sólo apartado, así que me has enseñado dos cosas. Nuevamente, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido. Java es enorme, poco a poco :-)